# Passing multi-line command output to echo outputs only a single line

Tags: linux, bash, parameter-passing, command-substitution

I have 2 files in my folder as shown below

```
$ ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user-group 0 May 10 14:49 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user-group 0 May 10 14:49 test1
```

Listing the files is showing normal. But why does below command shows both the lines merged in a single line in bash?

```
$ echo `ls -l`
total 1 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user-group 0 May 10 14:49 test -rw-r--r-- 1 user user-group 0 May 10 14:49 test1
```

Comment: Read _word splitting_, _glob expansion_, what is _$()_ and so on...

Comment: `echo "$(ls -l)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using command substitution here and echo, inorder to get echo to show your output on multiple lines you will need to quote the output.

```
$ echo "`ls -l`"
```

Comment: Nicely done; worth adding that [modern command-substitution syntax `$(...)` is preferable to legacy syntax `\`...\``](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 7):

To complement [Colwin's effective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43893666/45375) with ***why* the double quotes are needed**:

If you pass an ***unquoted* command substitution** (e.g, `` `ls -l` `` or, [better, `$(ls -l)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)) **or variable reference** (e.g., `$var`), **the *shell* modifies the command output / variable value *before* passing the argument to the command**.
This applies to all POSIX-compatible shells, not just `bash`.

Specifically, the following so-called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)
 are performed:

- **word-splitting**: the output is split into (potentially) *multiple* words by *whitespace*, including newlines (by default; the split characters can be set via `$IFS`)
- **globbing (filename expansion)**: each resulting word is interpreted as a *filename pattern* and matched agains files in the current directory, and each matching filename becomes its own word, with all resulting words replacing the original word; by default, if nothing matches, the word is left as-is.

The **resulting words are then passed *as individual arguments*** to the target command.

By contrast, **if you *double-quote* a command substitution (`"$(ls -l)"` or variable reference (`"$var"`), these expansions do NOT take place, and the output / value is passed *as-is*** to the target command.

---

Therefore, in the case at hand:

- the shell removes all newlines from the output of `ls -l`
- and then passes the resulting words *individually*, as *multiple arguments* to `echo`

`echo` simply concatenates *multiple* arguments you pass to it with spaces, which is why you're seeing the single-line output printed in your question.

**In short: Due to not double-quoting `` `ls -l` ``, `` echo `ls -l` `` prints a space-separated, single-line list of the words contained in the output from `ls -l`.**