# Powershell - Problem with Get-Childitem -include

Tags: powershell, include

I’m trying to write a PowerShell script that will allow a user to pass in a parameter with multiple types of files they want to process (i.e. *.txt and *.docx).  When I run the Get-Childitem command with the -include option and manually type in the file types, it works file.  But when I try to supply a variable for the -include mask, it does not work (returns nothing).

The problem only occurs when I’m using multiple file types
$incFiles = “””*.txt””`, “”*.docx”””

If I use a single file type, it works just fine.
$incFiles = “*.txt”

```
$incFiles = ""
$incFiles = """*.txt""`, ""*.docx"""
Write-Host "Manual Method:" '"*.txt", "*.docx"'
Write-Host "Calcul Method:" $incFiles

Write-Host "`nManual method works"
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\users\paul\Downloads" -Recurse -Include "*.txt", "*.docx"

Write-Host "This does not work"
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\users\paul\Downloads" -Recurse -Include $incFiles

Write-Host "End"
```

**Results**

```
Manual Method: "*.txt", "*.docx"
Calcul Method: "*.txt", "*.docx"

Manual method works

Directory: C:\users\paul\Downloads\Test2
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                           
-a----        3/28/2020   9:54 AM              0 File1.txt                                                                                                                      
-a----        3/28/2020   9:55 AM              0 File2.docx                                                                                                                     

This does not work

End
```

Comment: `$incFiles = """*.txt""`, ""*.docx"""` --> `$incFiles = "*.txt", "*.docx"`. You are 'over-quoting' and even have a backtick in there.

Comment: To add to Theo’s comment, your “manual” method is creating an array of two separate string values ```*.txt``` and ```*.docx ```, but because of your “overquoting”, ```$incFiles``` is a single string value ```"*.txt", "*.docx"```.

Answer (score 0):

[Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) have provided crucial pointer in comments on the question:

> `` $incFiles = """*.txt""`, ""*.docx""" ``

creates a *single string*, whose *verbatim content* ends up as `"*.txt", "*.docx"`.

<sup>As an aside: the backtick (`` ` ``), PowerShell's escape character, isn't necessary, given that `,` has no special meaning inside `"..."` (an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)).</sup>

While that *looks like* an *array literal* as you would pass it *directly* to a parameter that accepts an array of string values (such as `-Include` in this case), what you're passing is a *single string*, which is interpreted as a *single* wildcard pattern, and will therefore not work.

What you're trying to do would require PowerShell to parse the *content of the string* being passed as *PowerShell source code* - i.e., would require an additional evaluation round - which it (fortunately) doesn't do.<sup>[1]</sup>

**PowerShell, unlike other shells, is capable of passing values of any type as direct arguments to commands**, whether via a variable (`$incFiles`, in your case) or via an expression / nested command, using `(...)`; e.g., `Write-Host -Foreground Yellow ('-' * 10)`)

Therefore, **construct your `$incFiles` variable as an *array* of strings**, and **pass that array *as-is*** to the `-Include` parameter:

```
# Create a string array of wildcard expressions.
# (an [object[]] instance whose elements are of type [string]).
# Note the use of '...' rather than "...", which clearly signals that
# the enclosed text should be taken *verbatim* (rather than being subject to
# *expansion* (string interpolation).
$incFiles = '*.txt', '*.docx'

# Pass the array as-is to -Include
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\users\paul\Downloads" -Recurse -Include $incFiles
```

For a comprehensive overview of how PowerShell parses unquoted arguments passed to commands, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, POSIX-like shells such as `bash` do apply additional evaluation to unquoted variable references to a limited extent, via so-called *shell expansions* - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43896113/45375).</sup>